# Scroll view in React incorrectly resetting to top on Android stock browser when using setState

Tags: android, reactjs, android-browser, react-native-web

I created a simple [web app](https://plausible-ferry.glitch.me/) ([source code](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/plausible-ferry?path=src/App/index.js:1:0)) using [react-native-web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web) with a `ScrollView` and a `Text` at the top of the screen that gets updated with the `ScollView`'s y offset using `setState` on my component. Everything works fine in Chrome but when I run this on an Android 4.3 emulator's stock browser there are two issues:

1. When scrolling ends, I get a `onScroll` event with a `contentOffset.y` of 0:
   [image]
2. When scrolling ends, sometimes the ScrollView will jump back to the top of its content:
   [image]

Here it is working correctly on Chrome:

[image]

If I remove the `setState` call it prevents this issue from happening (but then I can't track the scroll offset which is what I want to do). Also I made sure that `shouldComponentUpdate` is implement so it's not re-rendering the `ScrollView`.

I don't want to file an issue on the react-native-web repo about this as [the author has said it won't officially support Android < 4.4](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/issues/615#issuecomment-324837842). It's not clear to me if this is an issue with React or react-native-web running on older browsers. Note that to get this to render on Android 4.3 I had to use [this fork](https://github.com/lyahdav/react-native-web/tree/fix-i18n-animations-react-15-with-flexbox-old-fixes) of react-native-web.

UPDATE:
After some more digging, I doubt this is a bug with react-native-web because I can reproduce it if I just use a plain `View` with some styling to make it overflow like a `ScrollView`. Could it be that React has a bug on these older stock Android browsers? If I find some time I will try to create a test web app with the bug without react-native-web.